# How do I display hatching labels in a different route measure unit than my coordinate system?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, linear-referencing

I have a route that crosses several states from west to east which is in the  USA_Contiguous_Lambert_Conformal_Conic coordinate system. The linear unit of this coordinate system is in meters. I would like to keep this coordinate system because it has good distance accuracy but I need to display my hatching in miles. I have set it up so that the hatches are displayed every mile (hatch interval of 1609.34 m). When I label these hatches my labels are of course in meters. What is the easiest way to display my labels in miles? Is there an easier way than building a text expression?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get around this by editing my coordinate system to display in miles.